# Creating NetworkX graph from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am trying to build a network where nodes are people's name and edges are created between nodes/people that have a relationship index greater than `0.60`.

The data are from pandas

```
Name      Relationship index
Julie        0.4
Marie        0.2
Bob          0.7 
Mark         0.85
Chris        0.43
```

What I have done is to get a linear representation of the table:

```
dat = df.set_index('Name').stack()
```

then try t establish connection between people having `relationship index > 0.6`:

```
dat = dat[dat['Relationship index']>0.6]
```

and get the edge list:

```
edges = dat.index.tolist()
```

Then I have been building the networks as bipartite graph:

```
G = nx.Graph(edges)
Gp = nx.bipartite.project(G, dat.set_index('Name').columns)

Gp.edges()
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error:

```
----> 2 dat = dat[dat['Relationship index']>0.6]

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Relationship index'
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Expected output:

A graph where Bob and Mark are connected to each other and other people are disconnected.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand. In the data you share, Mark has a relationship index of 0.85. But who with?

Comment: Hi warped. All nodes having relationship index greater than 0.6 have a relationship with each other (the problem is more complex, this is just a simplified version ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is not working in your code:

```
dat = df.set_index('Name').stack()
this line gets rid of column names, 
so you cannot access them with ['Relationship index']
anymore
```

For your specific problem, you can use itertools:

```
import itertools

matches = df[df['Relationship index']>.6]['Name'].tolist()
edges = itertools.product(matches, matches)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(df['Name'])
G.add_edges_from(edges)

nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @warped. I am getting this error: `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute 'is_numlike'`. Do you think is something due to some package?

Comment: @Math [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53421905/matplotlib-attributeerror-module-matplotlib-cbook-has-no-attribute-define-a) says that the error is due to matplotlib being installed in two different ways. So, this should not have anything to do with networkx, and everything with the code that draws the graph.