# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute 'iterable'

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

When I run this code:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.complete_graph(5)

nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

I got this error: `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute 'iterable'`

How can I get rid of that error? And thank you.

P.S. I run that code in the cloud, not on my laptop.

Comment: Maybe some versions are out of sync? You could try to upgrade both networkx and matplotlib.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute '\_define\_aliases'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53421905/matplotlib-attributeerror-module-matplotlib-cbook-has-no-attribute-define-a)

Comment: It does not help. I upgraded both networkx and matplotlib but the error remain.

Answer (score 8):

Just ran into this issue and found that upgrading `networkx` works perfectly

```
pip install --upgrade networkx
```

Answer (score 7):

Downgrade matplotlib version to 2.2.3

https://github.com/palash1992/GEM/issues/51

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your networkx version can also do

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).