# ImportError: cannot import name 'ls_mapper' from 'matplotlib.cbook'

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

```
       ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [10], in <cell line: 3>()
          1 import pandas as pd
          2 import sys
    ----> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
          4 import seaborn as sns
          5 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')


ImportError: cannot import name 'ls_mapper' from 'matplotlib.cbook'
```

What is wrong? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53421905/matplotlib-attributeerror-module-matplotlib-cbook-has-no-attribute-define-a

Comment: Yeah it helped me! Thanks! But the version of matplotlib degraded to 2.2.x from 3.2.x . So,is it specific issue in this version 3.2.x or any other problem related?