# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute '_Stack'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, miniconda

I am running the following code in pycharm:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()

fig.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

I have gotten this to work previously. Suddenly it is returning the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NoraBuggy\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  File "C:\Users\NoraBuggy\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1598, in subplots
    fig = figure(**fig_kw)
  File "C:\Users\NoraBuggy\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 934, in figure
    manager = new_figure_manager(
  File "C:\Users\NoraBuggy\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 465, in new_figure_manager
    return _get_backend_mod().new_figure_manager(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NoraBuggy\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3396, in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "C:\Users\NoraBuggy\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3401, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    return cls.FigureCanvas.new_manager(figure, num)
  File "C:\Users\NoraBuggy\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1785, in new_manager
    return cls.manager_class.create_with_canvas(cls, figure, num)
  File "C:\Users\NoraBuggy\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2680, in create_with_canvas
    return cls(canvas_class(figure), num)
  File "C:\Users\NoraBuggy\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 522, in __init__
    super().__init__(canvas, num)
  File "C:\Users\NoraBuggy\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2654, in __init__
    self.toolbar = self._toolbar2_class(self.canvas)
  File "C:\Users\NoraBuggy\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 669, in __init__
    NavigationToolbar2.__init__(self, canvas)
  File "C:\Users\NoraBuggy\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2844, in __init__
    self._nav_stack = cbook._Stack()
  File "C:\Users\NoraBuggy\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\__init__.py", line 217, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute '_Stack'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Matplotlib was working fine earlier today. This error started after I tried plotting something using seaborn, which gave me a similar error, so I uninstalled seaborn. Now, I am stuck with this error message when I try to plot anything.

I saw a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53421905/matplotlib-attributeerror-module-matplotlib-cbook-has-no-attribute-define-a) that suggested making sure you don't have multiple versions of matplotlib installed.

I ran the following in the pycharm terminal:

```
conda list matplotlib
```

which gave me this:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\NoraBuggy\miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
matplotlib                3.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-base           3.8.0            py39h4ed8f06_0
```

I tried uninstalling matplotlib-base, and then `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` gave me an error that matplotlib was not installed.

Comment: How about uninstall matplotlib too, and reinstall matplotlib?

Comment: Do not install / remove packages from conda with pip. If a package exists in a conda channel, then you should always use `conda install package`. Unless you’re using an embedded device (raspberry pi), or something else with limited hd and memory, use Anaconda instead of miniconda

Comment: This issue is not reproducible. It's an installation issue with your environment.

Comment: For me this issue is reproducible on Windows x64 and Python 3.11 if `matplotlib` version is 3.8.0 or higher. If I downgrade to the latest `matplotlib` 3.7.x, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

unistall matplotlib and try this:

```
pip install matplotlib==2.2.3
```

and try this :

```
pip install networkx --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing matplotlib to 3.7.2 from 3.8.* solved the problem for me